# Какую версию Python выбрать?

Tags: python

Собираюсь изучать питон. Но все не знаю с какой версии начать. Помогите сделать выбор. 
Область применения самая обширная:

- web;
- обработка биржевых данных, графиков, графический анализ;
- для себя.

Я бы выбрал 3-ю. Но останавливает наличие библиотек. Да и джанга под третью версию не работает. Вот ключевой вопрос как быстро это все появиться под 3-кой? Ведь на дворе 2012 год уже.

Comment: На сколько мне известно джанга 1,5 будет в экспериментальном режиме и сразу на ней делать сайты, я думаю не стоит. Так же осенью не будут портированы и другие библиотеки. Для примера тот же Twisted готов только на половину. И такие моменты меня сейчас смущают. 
Так же полезно знать, не будет ли проблем с обновлением джанги с 1,4 до 1,5 ?

Comment: На сколько я понял различия в синтаксисе не большие ?

Comment: Да, синтаксические различия можно по пальцам пересчитать. Куда больше различий в модулях и C API.

Какие-то модули переименованы, какие-то работают немного иначе, а каких-то и вовсе присутствуют только в одной из версий.

Comment: А какие еще можно фреймворки на python 3 использовать ?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, у вас не получится полностью отказаться от Python 2, так или иначе вам придется с ним сталкиваться. Однако, это вовсе не значит, что стоит отказываться от Python 3, кардинальных отличий между этими версиями не так уж и много, а основная проблема совместимости заключается именно в модулях.

По этому, я бы рекомендовал учить обе версии. Начните, к примеру, с Python 3, а затем изучите [отличия версий](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html). Когда начнется массовый переход на Python 3, уверен, вам пригодятся знания обоих версий.

Наиболее популярные веб фреймворки для Python 3:

- [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) - Bottle is a fast, simple and lightweight WSGI micro web-framework for Python. It is distributed as a single file module and has no dependencies other than the Python Standard Library.
- [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/about) - Pyramid is a very general open source Python web framework. As a framework, its primary job is to make it easier for a developer to create an arbitrary web application. The type of application being created isn’t really important; it could be a spreadsheet, a corporate intranet, or a social networking platform. Pyramid is general enough that it can be used in a wide variety of circumstances.
- [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) - CherryPy is a pythonic, object-oriented web framework. CherryPy allows developers to build web applications in much the same way they would build any other object-oriented Python program. This results in smaller source code developed in less time.

Comment: На практике сейчас ситуация такая: «Модуль также поддерживает и Python 3». Так что, я считаю, практичнее всё же начинать с 2.7 и потом, когда правилом станет «Модуль также поддерживает и Python 2.7» посмотреть на «отличия версий» :)

Хотя у меня складывается впечатление, что всё же к осени многие постараются перевести свои живые творения на 3.3. Хотя 3.3 всё ещё не идеален…

Comment: Можно и в таком порядке - это не принципиально. Просто Python 3 интереснее и, как следствие, изучать его проще.

> Хотя у меня складывается впечатление, что всё же к осени многие постараются перевести свои живые творения на 3.3

Думаю, что к осени вряд-ли. Вот когда для Python 3 стабильная версия Django выйдет, тогда наверняка и все остальные подтянуться.

Answer (score 2):

Ну я бы посоветовал взять литературу по Python 3, например от Марка Саммерфилда. В его книгах подробно описаны отличия некоторых конструкций языка между Python 3 и Python 2. А вообще, товарищ Ilya Pirogov прав - отказаться от Python 2 не получиться. У меня у самого куча проектов на Django 1.4, а так же еще на Django 1.3.1 и не факт, что 1.5 "с лету" войдет в обиход, т.к. очень много сторонних модулей используют Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

Начинать следует с версии 2*, потому что она еще долго будет востребованной, но потом, когда наметится массовая тенденция к переходу на 3 ветку, тебе придется изучить лишь отличия новой ветки от старой.

Answer (score 0):

Джанга 1.5 будет этой осенью и должна (по планам) поддерживать 3-й питон. Точнее 3.3 (релиз которого также запланирован осень), в которой некоторые жёсткие требования 3-й ветки будут смягчены. Но по большому счёту какой питон изучать разницы нет, т.к. концептуальных различий нет, а софт во многих ситуациях конвертируется простым скриптом 2to3.

Answer (score 0):

"Джанга" как ты назвал Django, работает под 3-м питоном, хотя я как пример использую Python2.6+Django1.4, проблем нет. Я бы выбрал исключительно 3-й, но сам не перехожу т.к. много проектов именно на 2.6

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент надо знать обе версии. Думаю, через 2-3 года все основные фреймворки и библиотеки будут поддерживать Python3. Но в конторах и проектах еще останется куча работающего кода на Python2.x, который нужно поддерживать, а переписывать заново на 3 никто не собирается. Так что профессионал должен учить обе версии, благо, они не так уж и сильно различаются.